# awswrangler query Athenea: AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Tags: amazon-athena, aws-data-wrangler

I have one table in Athena which all columns with proper datatypes(date, bigint,int,decimal(28,2) string and etc.).
I need to query out the data via aws wrangler API :athena.read_sql_query
I write: athena.read_sql_query(sql=test_query, database=test_db, ctas_approach=False)
But in the glue I have error like below:
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
I do have some cols with date format in 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

May I know how load the df in the Glue? Which parameter do I need to change?

Thanks

I do need the actual data type and do not want to cast them all in varchar.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed by change the max date from 9999-12-31 to max date in pandas.
See:https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21972